# How execute one animation before run window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying run one animation and after go to other page with ***window.location.href***, but I can't do it!

It run link with other page before that animation finish itself.

**CSS:**

```
#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 415;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="backInit()">Back</button>
<div id="main">...</div>
```

I tried two ways:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    document.getElementById('main').style.left = 0;
} );

// Way 1
function backInit() {
    setTimeout(run(), 2000);
    setTimeout(returnInit(),2000);
}

// Way 2
function backInit() {
    run().then( function() { window.location.href = baseURL + '/init.html'; } );
}

function run() {
    document.getElementById('main').style.left = 415;
}
```

I need help with this!

Thanks!

Comment: The setTimeouts are starting counting the delay as soon as they are called. Why not simply use `2000` for the first and `4000` for the second?

Comment: I get it! I will test on this way and I post here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unfortunately the js will not listen to the css transition time .. Instead of that you can use `.animate()` in jquery and use its callback function to redirect

This is how it can be done using jquery

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#main').css('left' , 0);
});

function run() {
    $('#main').animate({'left' : 415} , 500 , function(){
       window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
    });
}
```

```css
#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="run()">Back</button>
<div id="main">...</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Mohamed-Yousef. It works but I did to need to do one alteration for the animate seem more clean.

Comment: Thank you brother!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like following.

```js
function run() {
  console.log("Executing immediately(do your animation here)");
  setTimeout(returnInit, 2000);
}

function returnInit() {
  console.log("Executing after 2 seconds (do your navigation here)");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">Start</button>
```

**Edit:**

You should not call `setTimeout` like following.

```
 setTimeout(run(), 2000);
 setTimeout(returnInit(),2000);
```

Otherwise it will execute the function immediately, you should change it like following.

```
 setTimeout(run, 2000);
 setTimeout(returnInit,2000);
```

Comment: Don't work man! It continue to go to init.html without run animation! :(

Comment: I have updated my answer for the possible cause, you can have a look and let me know if your issue gets fixed?

Comment: Excuse me @PSK! I had not understood your answer. Really it was a noob wrong, the parentheses!
Yes! Your answer worked very well too! I had already modified my code for jquery as in the answer above that I marked as solution but the true wrong was the parentheses "( )" together with the function.
Thank you brother!

Answer (score 1):

You did not it add the animation so try this:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    document.getElementById('main').style.left = 0;
} );

// Way 1
function backInit() {
    setTimeout(run(), 2000);
    setTimeout(returnInit(),10000);
}


function run() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("main");   
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    if (pos == 415) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 

      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
}
function returnInit() {

  window.location.href ='https://stackoverflow.com/'; 
}
```

```css
#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 415;
  
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="backInit()">Back</button>
<div id="main">...</div>
```

Comment: Hey @i_th I copied your code and it executes half-part. The animation works but the window.location.href no.

Comment: Hey @i_th sorry! I wrong with your code and now I tested right. It back on same thing. It run location but don't the animate. Did you test this code??

Comment: @it runs for both.

Comment: Nice @i_th! Here after that I tested with patience, works too!